# Get next value on a map?

Tags: swift, functional-programming

I'm trying to compare element to next element in a collection.

For example :

```
let array: [(Double, String)]= [(2.3, "ok"),
                                (1.4, "ok"),
                                (5.1, "notOk")]
```

I need a returned array who will summary element where the string is the same. So my result will be :

```
new array = [(3.7, "ok"), (5.1, "notOk")]
```

I need to do it functional if possible. i tried to get next element in a map but can't found how.

Something like this (this is just for logic, this code isn't working.

```
let newArray = array.map {(element, nextElement) in 
    if element.1 == nextElement.1 {
        return element.0 + nextElement.0 
    }
}
```

Comment: So do you want to summarize only elements that are neighbors AND that have the same string, or do you just want so summarize depending on the string (i.e. it is not important that they are next to each other)?

Comment: Do you want to sum only two elements or all in a sequence? You need to be more precise, i.e. what will be the result of `(1,"notok"),(2,"ok"),(3,"ok"),(4,"ok"),(5,"ok"),(6,"ok"),(7,"notok")`?

Comment: @DrummerB I want to add every element wich contain the same string. in your example the result will be [(20, "ok"), (8, "notok")]

Comment: @AndreasOetjen All element, the order doesn't have importance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a more functional way:

```
let array: [(Double, String)]= [(2.3, "ok"),
                                (1.4, "ok"),
                                (5.1, "notOk")]
let keys = Set(array.map{$0.1})            // find unique keys
let result = keys.map { key -> (Double, String) in   
    let sum = array.filter {$0.1 == key}   // find all entries with the current key
                   .map {$0.0}             // map them to their values
                   .reduce(0, +)           // sum the values
    return (sum, key)
}
print(result)
```

Output:

> [(5.0999999999999996, "notOk"), (3.6999999999999997, "ok")]

Alternatively (suggested by @dfri):

```
let keys = Set(array.map{$0.1})            // find unique keys
let result = keys.map { key -> (Double, String) in   
    let sum = array.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.1 == key ? $1.0 : 0) }
    return (sum, key)
}
```

Comment: Thank's, it's look like what i'm trying to do, just for the keys, i've to do $0[index].1 to access. How can i solve it ? I don't know why map doesn't gave me just the element

Comment: This shows a neat approach, but note that the chained `filter`, `map` and `reduce`, while semantically sound, could be somewhat wasteful, and could alternatively be reduced (no pun intended) to a single `reduce` call on `array` (e.g. `let sum = array.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.1 == key ? $1.0 : 0) }`). Moreover, if we prefer brevity over clarity, we could further refactor the body of the `map` call above to a single expression, `let result = keys.map { key in (array.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.1 == key ? $1.0 : 0) }, key) }`.

Comment: @dfri Thanks, I added your suggestion to my answer.

Comment: @dfri: Yes, I had a single call in the map in my initial suggestion, but changed it for clarity.

Comment: Yeah I also believe clarity is to prefer in this case. If you're curious, note that the need for the explicit type annotation for the return type of the `map` call (`(Double, String)`; something I wish we could leave out) is a known limitation for (some) closures; closures that contains more than a single expression. So the only reason to refactor into a single-expression`map` call would be to avoid the explicit type annotation of the return type (which, imo, is a bad call here: better to stick to clarity as you've done!).

Comment: Ah, so that's the reason why it couldn't infer the return type. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Happy to help. If you're interesting in reading more on this particular "issue", see JIRA bug report [SR-1570](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1570), particularly Jordans first comment (_"This is correct behaviour ..."_), as well as the lower-most answer by Jordan in the [following Swift Evolution thread](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20151214/002583.html).

Comment: Not sure that you've seen my comment. The first Set + map gave me the array and not the element to $0 so $0.1 doesn't exist, but $0[index].1 yes. How solve it ?

Comment: @Makaille I'm not sure what you mean. `keys` will be an array of strings: ["ok", "notOk"]

Comment: @DrummerB yes of course, the problem is in this line let keys = Set(array.map{$0.1})   . $0 = all the array and not just the current mapped element.

Comment: @Makaille and you defined the array like in your question?

Comment: @Makaille I updated my answer with the complete code and output. I'm using Swift 3.

Comment: @DrummerB Yes, was just a problem from an optionnal. Perfect, thank's to you and dfri ! Awesome knowledge.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is O(m*n) and at worst is O(n^2). For small lists, that's fine, but this scales poorly for large lists with many keys.

Answer (score 4):

I like alexburtnik's answer. It's basically word for word how I wrote my first pass of this. It's straightforward, clear, and efficient. It is excellent Swift.

But functional programming can help us think more deeply about problems and create better, reusable tools. So let's think functionally.

dfri's solution appears beautiful, but is O(m*n) (in the worst case, O(n^2)). It loops through the entire array for every unique key. This gets back the old adage by Alan Perlis: "A Lisp programmer knows the value of everything and the cost of nothing." But functional programming doesn't have to be inefficient.

The point of functional programming is to break down complex problems into simpler problems, make those simpler problems generic, and then recombine them. It's not about filters and flatMaps.

So let's break down this problem. We want to group by key, and then sum the values for each key. Grouping by key is going to be a lot easier if we sort by key first:

```
let result = array
    .sorted(by: { $0.1 < $1.1 })
```

Now, we wish we could group them with something like this:

```
let result = array
    .sorted(by: { $0.1 < $1.1 })
    .grouped(by: { $0.1 == $1.1 })
```

I wish I had that `grouped(by:)`. [Wish fulfillment is the heart of functional programming](http://robnapier.net/functional-wish-fulfillment), so let's write it. Well, a group is a sequence of elements that are all "equal" for some value of "equal." We could build that this way:

```
extension Array {
    func grouped(by equal: (Element, Element) -> Bool) -> [[Element]] {
        guard let firstElement = first else { return [] }
        guard let splitIndex = index(where: { !equal($0, firstElement) } ) else { return [self] }
        return [Array(prefix(upTo: splitIndex))] + Array(suffix(from: splitIndex)).grouped(by: equal)
    }
```

That said, I don't really like this code. It's not very Swifty. That `[Array(prefix(...)] +` is a good indication of how much Swift hates us doing it this way. And it can be very expensive due to copying (probably getting us back to O(n^2). The Swiftier solution would be an Sequence:

```
struct GroupedSequence<Element>: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
    var elements: [Element]
    let equal: (Element, Element) -> Bool
    private var nextIndex = 0
    init(of elements: [Element], by equal: @escaping (Element, Element) -> Bool) {
        self.elements = elements
        self.equal = equal
    }

    mutating func next() -> ArraySlice<Element>? {
        guard nextIndex < elements.endIndex else { return nil }
        let first = elements[nextIndex]
        let splitIndex = elements[nextIndex..<elements.endIndex].index(where: { !equal($0, first) } ) ?? elements.endIndex
        defer { nextIndex = splitIndex }
        return elements[nextIndex..<splitIndex]
    }
}

extension Array {
    func grouped(by equal: @escaping (Element, Element) -> Bool) -> GroupedSequence<Element> {
        return GroupedSequence(elements: self, equal: equal)
    }
}
```

Yes, it mutates and it's a little more code, but it's also lazy (which is a key tool from functional programming), it's better Swift, and very reusable. I like it. But you can use the recursive, pure version if you like.

OK, so now we have an array of arrays that are equivalent. We want to map over those and reduce each element to its sum. So we'll have a reduce inside a map. But this is not O(n^2) because each reduce is only over a single slice. We're going to walk every element just one time.  To take care of one impossible corner case (an empty group, which `grouped(by:)` will never actually create), we'll use `flatMap`, but it's really just a map. You might be tempted to jump to this, but don't do it:

```
let result: [(Double, String)] = array
    .sorted(by: { $0.1 < $1.1 })
    .grouped(by: { $0.1 == $1.1 })
    .flatMap { group in
        guard let key = group.first?.1 else { return nil }
        return (group.reduce(0, { $0 + $1.0 }), // Sum of our values
                key)
}
```

Why? That's horribly unreadable. This is what gives functional programming a bad name. What the heck is that last piece doing? No, we want functional composition, not just functional tools. So we extract a function:

```
func sumEach(pairGroup: ArraySlice<(Double, String)>) -> (Double, String)? {
    guard let key = pairGroup.first?.1 else { return nil }
    return (pairGroup.reduce(0, { $0 + $1.0 }), // Sum of our values
        key)
}
```

Now, we can have our nice functional approach without sacrificing comprehension:

```
let result = array
    .sorted(by: { $0.1 < $1.1 })
    .grouped(by: { $0.1 == $1.1 })
    .flatMap(sumEach(pairGroup:))
```

And in the process we've created a new tool, grouping, that we can use to compose other solutions. I think that's pretty nice.

But I'd still probably do it alexburtnik's way.

Comment: A big thank's to you, this is so interesting, it's awesome. This is not the easiest approach but i'll try to apply it in the futur. I'm loving swift and functionnal programing so thank's again for you knowledge

Comment: I'll point out that I merely refactored the body of the `map` call in the existing approach in DrummerB's answer (jumping at the non-lazy nested `filter`, `map` and `reduce`), but it was a true oversight to miss that that existing approach was `O(n^2)`, which might quickly become an issue in practice. Possibly worth adding for those interested in complexity that due to the `sorted` call, the final approach above will be `O(n log n)`, on average, as compared to alexburtnik's `O(n)` approach. Not that the prior is likely to become an issue in practice, though. Great post here, as always!

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over every tupple in your input array and save a sum in a dictionary like this:

```
let array: [(Double, String)] = [(1.0,"notok"),(2.0,"ok"),(3.0,"ok"),(4.0,"ok"),(5.0,"ok"),(6.0,"ok"), (7.0,"notok")]

var dict = [String: Double]()
for (value, key) in array {
    dict[key] = (dict[key] ?? 0) + value
}
print ("dict: \(dict)")
```

Output:

> dict: ["notok": 8.0, "ok": 20.0]

If you really need to get an array of tuples, use this:

```
let result = dict.map { (key, value) in (value, key) }
print ("result: \(result)")
```

Output:

> result: [(8.0, "notok"), (20.0, "ok")]

Answer (score 1):

I guess that a solution that makes a good use of Swift's features would be to combine **filter** and **reduce**:

```
    let array: [(String, Double)] = [("ok", 2.4),
                                     ("ok", 1.3),
                                     ("not ok", 4.4),
                                     ("very not ok", 99.0)]
    let key = "ok"
    let result = array.filter({$0.0 != key}) + [array.filter({ $0.0 == key }).reduce((key, 0.0), { (key, $0.1 + $1.1) })]
    print(result)
```

And then the result would be

> [("not ok", 4.4000000000000004), ("very not ok", 99.0), ("ok", 3.7000000000000002)]

Which I assume is what you wanted to achieve.

EDIT:

To reduce all tuples you could simply wrap the solution inside of a function:

```
    func reduceAllTuples(tupleArray: [(String, Double)]) -> [(String, Double)]{
        var array = tupleArray
        for (key, _) in tupleArray {
            array = array.filter({$0.0 != key}) + [array.filter({ $0.0 == key }).reduce((key, 0.0), { (key, $0.1 + $1.1) })]
        }
        return array
    }
```

Comment: This will sum up only "ok" tuples, but will ignore others. If you have `("not ok", 4.4), ("not ok", 4)`, you won't get `("not ok", 8.4)`,